# error en persistence.xml, problemas con hibernate. persistence

Tags: java, web, jsp, jpa

En los ultimos dias he estado intentando hacer una aplicación web por JSP, java y mysql conector 8. Me ha dado un error cuando intento ejecutarlo, supongo que es el orden en el persistence pero no tengo nada en concreto

mi error es

org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        federacion
        org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

mi codigo de la clase modelo es:

package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
   import javax.persistence.*;

/**
    * The persistent class for the USUARIO database table.
    * 
    */
   @Entity
   @Table(name="USUARIO")
   @NamedQuery(name="Usuario.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
   public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
private int idUSUARIO;

private int UNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD;

public Usuario() {
}

public int getIdUSUARIO() {
    return this.idUSUARIO;
}

public void setIdUSUARIO(int idUSUARIO) {
    this.idUSUARIO = idUSUARIO;
}

public int getUNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD() {
    return this.UNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD;
}

public void setUNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD(int UNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD) {
    this.UNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD = UNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD;
}
```

}
mi codigo de la clase control es:

```
import model.Usuario;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Entity
public class ControlUsuario {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;
    private List<Usuario> _Usuario;
    private Usuario Usuario;

    public ControlUsuario() {
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("federacion");
        this.em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
        this._Usuario = consultarUsuario();
        this.Usuario = new Usuario();
    }

    public List<Usuario> consultarUsuario() {
        String jpql = " select * from USUARIO";
        Query query = this.em.createQuery(jpql);
        List<Usuario> _Usuario = query.getResultList();
        return _Usuario;
    }

    public Usuario loginUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        for (int a = 0; a < _Usuario.size(); a++) {
            if (usuario.getIdUSUARIO() == _Usuario.get(a).getIdUSUARIO()
                    && usuario.getUNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD() == _Usuario.get(a).getUNIVERSIDAD_idUNIVERSIDAD()) {
                System.out.println("logeo satisfactorio");
            } else {
                System.out.println("logeo no satisfactorio");
                usuario = null;
            }
        }
        return usuario;
    }

    public void crearUsuario() {
        try {
            this.em.getTransaction().begin();
            this.em.persist(Usuario);
            this.em.getTransaction().commit();
            this.Usuario = new Usuario();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public List<Usuario> get_Usuario() {
        return _Usuario;
    }

    public void set_Usuario(List<Usuario> _Usuario) {
        this._Usuario = _Usuario;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return Usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario Usuario) {
        this.Usuario = Usuario;
    }
}
```

Mi código jsp donde se crea el conflicto es al iniciar la clase ControlUsuario:

```
<%
    ControlUsuario controlusuario = new ControlUsuario();
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
%>
```

El persistence es:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="federacion">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>federacion</jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>model.Servicio</class>
        <class>model.SERVICIO_has_UNIVERSIDAD</class>
        <class>model.Universidad</class>
        <class>model.Usuario</class>
        <class>control.ControlUsuario</class>
        <class>control.ControlServicio</class>
        <class>control.ControlServicio_has_Universidad</class>
        <class>control.ControlUniversidad</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/federacion" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="Unired2018*" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Mi pom, por si ese el problema, es:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FEDERACION</groupId>
    <artifactId>FEDERACION</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Creo que nos vendría bien toda la traza que tengas, tanto la de arranque de la aplicación web como la que sucede cuando te da el error

Comment: el error que me aparece en tomcat es este:     El Servlet.service() para servlet [jsp] lanzó una excepción
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Se ha encontrado contenido no válido a partir del elemento 'provider'. Se esperaba uno de '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":non-jta-data-source, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":mapping-file, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":jar-file,....} hay una pregunta que se respondio antes con el mismo error pero no es el caso de esta

Answer (score 0):

estos dias e estado trabajando en el proyecto, resulta que se me dio por eliminar dos lineas del persistence y funciono, pues me sigue generando errores pero ya son por parte mia. las lineas que elimines son

```
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>federacion</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

y modifique otra linea

```
<persistence-unit name="federacion" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aclararé lo que pasa.

En una unidad de persistencia `<pesistence-unit>` el valor del tipo de transacción por defecto depende del entorno en el que se ejecute JPA.

Existen dos entornos: *JavaEE* y *JavaSE*. Un entorno *JavaEE* quiere decir que la apliación se ejecuta en un contenedor de aplicaciones *JavaEE* (ahora *JakartaEE*), como *Payara* o *WildFly*. Un entorno *JavaSE* quiere decir que la aplicación se ejecuta sin un contenedor *JavaEE*, como una aplicación de escritorio o sobre un contenedor de aplicaciones web como *Tomcat*.

El valor del tipo de transacción por defecto (`transaction-type`) de una unidad de persistencia para cada entorno es:

JavaSE -> `RESOURCE_LOCAL`

JavaEE -> `JTA`

Pasa lo siguiente:

- `<jta-data-source>` se añade cuando el entorno es JavaEE.
- `<provider>` solo se debe añadir una vez. Lo añadiste dos veces.

Algo adicional:

JPA es una interfaz, Hibernate o EclipseLink son implementaciones (en JPA también conocidos como proveedores o providers). Si vas a usar Hibernate debes especificar la etiqueta de `<provider>` con los valores del proveedor de Hibernate, de igual manera, si usas EclipseLink, los valores del proveedor de EclipseLink.

**Explicación a la solución que descubriste:**

1. Por lo que parece, estás usando JPA en un entorno JavaSE, así que no había que poner: `<jta-data-source>federacion</jta-data-source>`
2. Solo se debe especificar como máximo un `<provider>`. Sin embargo, es opcional. Cuando no se coloca, creo que JPA lo optiene a partir de la implementación añadida.